# Lookup between two ranges

Tags: vba, excel, udf

Afternoon all, I'm working with two columns of data - one of these has an author name and the second has a publish date-time value. I'm looking to build up a UDF to take these two ranges, search the author column for a particular string and if found to return the value from the publish column.

Data looks similar to this;

[image]

Once it has found the author I'm looking for i want it to look at the publish time and find the minimum value for this.

For example, if i was looking for the author Ben in the above then the value returned should be 08/06/2014 17:15.

If the data i was working with was always in the same format then i would build up an array formula to create a MINIF but the columns these ranges show in are always different and the easiest option will be a UDF that the end user can just put the two ranges into.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers

Comment: Why not use Vlookup or Index/Match ?

Comment: You would need to put the same number of criteria in a UDF as you do with MINIFS(), so get everyone a subscription to Office 365 Excel and use: `=MINIFS(B:B,A:A"Ben")` or you can show us what you have tried with vba and where you got stuck.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Answer (score 1):

Your UDF might be like this, no office 365 features needed:

```
Function MinDateByAuthor(author As String, rngNames As Range, rngDates As Range) As Date
  MinDateByAuthor = Application.Evaluate("Aggregate(15, 6," & _
    rngDates.Address(External:=True) & "/(" & _
    rngNames.Address(External:=True) & "=""" & author & """),1)")
End Function
```

You can use it like `=MinDateByAuthor("Ben", A2:A100, B2:B100)`

You can also place some cell address instead of the hardcoded `"Ben"`.

TBH, all your UDF has done is facilitate a little bit typing the initial formula.
And you might want to make it even easier, by allowing full column references (`A:A, B:B`) without sensitive slowness. In the above UDF you *can* do that, but as suggested by @ScottCraner, we can make it work faster:

```
Function MinDateByAuthor2(author As String, ByVal rngNames As Range, ByVal rngDates As Range) As Date
  Set rngNames = Intersect(rngNames, rngNames.Parent.UsedRange)
  Set rngDates = Intersect(rngDates, rngDates.Parent.UsedRange)

  ' The rest is the same ...
  MinDateByAuthor2 = Application.Evaluate("Aggregate(15, 6," & _
    rngDates.Address(External:=True) & "/(" & _
    rngNames.Address(External:=True) & "=""" & author & """),1)")
End Function
```

Here you will notice that `=MinDateByAuthor2(A3,A:A,B:B)` calculates faster than `=MinDateByAuthor(A3,A:A,B:B)`.

Comment: AGGREGATE!!!!!! Way to go. Even though this is a close worthy question, I gave the `+1` for the use of AGGREGATE.  Hopefully the OP is using 2010 or later.

Comment: @ScottCraner lol, thanks, I know this is your bread and butter, but I'm a little hungry :P

Comment: One trick I have learned is we can allow the use of full column references is to add `set rngNames = intersect(rngNames,rngnames.parent.usedrange)`  This way the user can use the full column without detriment.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's a good idea... it's a puzzle why it's not done like that automatically in Excel. Well, I guess the guys must have found some serious flaws if it was integrated automatically.

Comment: As @Jeeped has commented, AGGREGATE seems to be a half baked formula.  It would not have taken that much to add it into the code of the function itself and make it a truly awesome function.

Comment: I was talking about the AGGREGATE function being half baked and how the developers should have taken a few more minutes to add the ability to use full column references, not yours.  Yours is great as is.

Comment: @ScottCraner I did it though, to deserve your upvote ;)

Comment: You can test that the ranges are the same size and exit the function if they are different.

Comment: My initial comment (that I removed) was if the misalignment in the two (truncated) arrays resulted from misalignment in the used ranges. But that's a very "theoretical" edge case. I believe however that this possibility prevented the MS folks from doing systematically such truncations.

Answer (score 0):

It's suppose to look like that, just change this row:

```
If Cells(x,1).Value="ben" Then 'or whatever name you chose
```

if you want it to be some other Author

```
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim a As Date

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows1 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      NumRows2 = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

      Range("A1").Select

      For x = 1 To NumRows1
           If Cells(x,1).Value="ben" Then 'or whatever name you chose
             If IsEmpty(a) Then
                A = Cells(x,2)
             End If
             If DateValue(Cells(x,2))<A Then
                  A = Cells(x,2)    
             End If
           End If
      Next
```